# How to edit ActiveMQ Artemis Attributes

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm new to ActiveMQ Artemis and unsure how to modify/edit/set any configurations (attributes) after creation of the address, or queues, or anything in there. On the web console, when I click on say an address or a queue, on the attribute tab, I can view tons of information like: Routing Type, Address, Role, Durable, etc... But when I click on a field, I can only view it, but there's no option to edit it.

I tried to shoot in the dark by creating a queue named "TestTopic" within the web console. Went to the broker folder and searched for that string using the following command:

```
grep -R "TestTopic" .
```

But no luck!

I then tried researching on the [java API doc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.activemq/artemis-core-client/latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/package-summary.html) itself, but they only have getter methods. And jolokia API only gives read-only data.

I thought that it might be because of my role which gives me read-only permission but that would be odd as the original user should have admin rights, and when I inspected it, it seems to be correct to me with a "set*" access method.

In artemis-roles.properties file:

```
amq = admin
```

In broker.xml file:

```xml
<security-settings>
   <security-setting match="#">
      <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
      <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
      <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
      <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
      <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
      <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
      <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
      <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
      <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
      <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
      <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
   </security-setting>
</security-settings>
```

In management.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<management-context xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
   <authorisation>
      <allowlist>
         <entry domain="hawtio"/>
      </allowlist>
      <default-access>
         <access method="list*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="get*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="is*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="set*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
      </default-access>
      <role-access>
         <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis">
            <access method="list*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="is*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="set*" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- Note count and browse are need to access the browse tab in the console-->
            <access method="browse*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="count*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
         </match>
      </role-access>
   </authorisation>
</management-context>
```

I'm running out of options on where to look for. If you guys can point me in the correct direction, it would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queues are essentially immutable. This is so that configuration changes don't unintentionally negatively impact the messages in the queue (e.g. changing a queue to durable = false and then restarting the broker only to find that all the durable messages in the queue have been dropped). The recommended way to "change" configuration would be to create a new queue with the configuration you want, move messages (if any) to that queue as necessary, & delete the old queue.

If you create a durable queue or address via the web console that data is persisted to the broker's "bindings" journal. It isn't written back to `broker.xml` which is why you can't find it using `grep`.